# How to get partial result in a concurrency timeout error?

Tags: python, threadpool, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am doing HTTP GET from some URLs in parallel and I wanna set an overall timeout, my code is pasted below. Sometimes some URLs return okay responses but others would cause the timeout exception to be thrown, I wonder how can I access the ones that did return okay in such cases?

```
try:
    results = list(self.executor.map(self._fetch_feature, urls, timeout = self.tecton_timeout))
    return results
except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError as e:
    # Some urls may have returned okay response, how to access them here?
```

I expect to be able to access the result of the threads that are properly finished.

Comment: You can try catching the timeout in each `self._fetch_feature` call itself, then just return `None` or some other token that way, so you at least have all valid returns. If you are catching the concurrent TimeoutError you're going to need a much weirder solution imo

Comment: You could retreive all results up until the first `TimoutError` by making the `try`-part more granular. But the moment a `TimeoutError` is raised while iterating over the generator returned by `.map` it is shut down (`StopIteration`) and you won't be able to retreive the rest of the results.